# MySQL и кодировка - проблемы

Tags: mysql

Все русские буквы отображаются вопросами.
Сравнение: `utf8_general_ci`

В хедере стоит: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />`

Как исправить кодировку?

Comment: С помощью mysql_client_encoding() узнал кодировку, возвращаемую базой данных, оказывается, это latin1. Но ведь я выставил сравнение utf8_general_ci, почему тогда latin1 возвращает?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

после подключения к базе данных задайте кодировку

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

Answer (score 2):

Создаёте, если его нет, файл **.htaccess**, туда прописываем строку:
**AddDefaultCharset UTF-8**
Сам файл должен находиться в корне сайта!

P.S. Если ваша база уже в UTF-8, то *SET NAMES ...* может не решить проблему.
Использование *mysql_query()* чтобы выполнить *SET NAMES...* не рекомендуется.
Лучше использовать *mysql_set_charset()*

Comment: У меня PHP 5.3.5, а mysql_set_charset() работает только на PHP не старше 5.2.3