# JDBC MySQL: проблемы с отображением русских символов

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, кодировка

Работаю с MySQL 5.5 через JDBC.

Либа JDBC - mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar.

Файл `my.ini` следующего содержимого:

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysqld]
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8
```

При подключении к БД указываю кодировку:

```
     static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
     static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/andrey3k?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8";

     static final String USER = "root";
     static final String PASS = "luxury1life";
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
        }

        try {
            stmt.executeQuery("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");
        } catch (SQLException e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            stmt.executeQuery("SET CHARACTER SET 'UTF8'");
        } catch (SQLException e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Но все равно при работе с БД, добавлении данных в таблицу вместо русских букв знаки вопроса.

В чем может быть дело ?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/51391/mysql-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B?rq=1

Comment: выполните `show create database имя_бд;` и `show create table имя_проблемной_таблицы;`, может быть таблицы созданы не в той кодировке. Еще я не уверен, что в url базы должно быть `&amp;`, а не `&`, или попробуйте задать эти параметры через `DriverManager.getConnection(String url, java.util.Properties info)`

Comment: таблицы созданы в UTF8, через java.util.Properties получается тоже самое